# Error running selenium ruby script through xvfb-run

Tags: ruby, linux, selenium, xvfb

What I'm trying to do

Use selenium and its ruby bindings to open chrome and read a value from the DOM. This portion works great however I need to run it on a linux server headlessly. Seemed easy enough so I ran it using xvfb-run using this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:./bin
xvfb-run --server-arg="-screen 0, 1024x768x16" ruby script.rb
```

The first line adds the binary `chromedriver` to `PATH` and the second lines runs the script through `xvfb`. I got this working on an EC2 ubuntu box which is essentially a dev box. Everything is great.

Now comes time to run it on another EC2 ubuntu box using the same bash script. It spits out an error that the `chromedriver` binary couldn't be found. Odd since it worked fine on the other box. I checked, the binary is there. I manually add it to the path and run the bash script again, same error. After some troubleshooting and googling I found this:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

This advises that the chromedriver needs to be symlink'd to `/usr/bin/google-chrome`. Again odd since it works fine on the other box and my local machine without this symlink. I symlinked it to this location and now this is the error I'm getting:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.41.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok': unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

I've never gotten this on my local or dev box. Any ideas? Is this an issue with `chromedriver`, `xvfb` or the environment its running in? Some difference in the deploy box that would be different than the dev box I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it but was avoiding it as it would involve code changes rather than how to run the code. I will give it a shot if I can't get a solution for this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Misunderstanding the directions [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). Installed `google-chrome` in `/usr/bin` and it worked.